# CGAffineTransform not working correctly with Auto Layout

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, autolayout, cgaffinetransform

I have this simple animation block:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:_CHANGE_VIEW_ANIMATION_SPEED
                      delay:0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                 animations:^{

                     aButton.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.8, 0.8);

                     aButton.alpha = 0;

                 }completion:^(BOOL finished ) {

                     aButton.selected = YES;
                     aButton.userInteractionEnabled = NO;

                     [UIView animateWithDuration:_CHANGE_VIEW_ANIMATION_SPEED
                                           delay:0
                                         options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                                      animations:^{

                                          aButton.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;

                                          aButton.alpha = 1;

                                      }completion:nil];


                 }];
```

If I disable Auto Layout the animation works correctly (which is odd because it's just a CGAffineTransform, I'm not changing any frames). With Auto Layout enabled it animates off center and not smoothly. No idea why.

Strangely enough the animation works perfectly in Xcode 6 Beta 3 with Auto Layout on.

Any ideas?

Comment: have you checked it on device? maybe it's just a simulator issue?

Comment: Just tried it, does the same thing. Run on Xcode 6 Beta 3 and works perfectly on device. Run on Xcode 5.1.1 and it runs strangely again.

Comment: Perhaps auto-layout is trying to adjust your button's `frame` when its transform is not the identity.  That's bound to lead to weirdness.  One thing you could try is to make `aButton` an instance of a `UIButton` subclass that overrides `setFrame:`.  Then (1) you can break in `setFrame:` and see if it's called during your animation and (2) you can potentially implement the override in such a way that `setFrame:` can be disabled during the animation.

Comment: Ok I'll give that a go, see what I find. Any ideas on why there would be a difference between Xcode versions?

Comment: It seems that interactions between transforms and auto-layout may be undefined.  In the Xcode5/iOS7 SDK, constraints seemed to be applied before transformations, now in Xcode6/iOS8 it appears to be the other way around.